# correlations between two scales with different number of items

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to get the correlations between two Likert scales: "ideal" and "approval". They include different number of items.

```
>names(ideal)
[1] "IDEAL1"       "IDEAL2"       "IDEAL3"       "IDEAL4"       "IDEAL5"      
  "PROMOTIONAL6"
>str(ideal)
'data.frame':   96 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ IDEAL1      : int  4 5 3 5 5 3 2 6 4 3 ...
 $ IDEAL2      : int  3 3 3 3 2 2 3 5 4 3 ...
 $ IDEAL3      : int  4 2 3 4 3 2 4 3 4 3 ...
 $ IDEAL4      : int  4 5 3 4 4 2 3 5 5 3 ...
 $ IDEAL5      : int  3 5 3 4 3 2 4 5 5 3 ...
 $ PROMOTIONAL6: int  3 2 3 2 2 1 4 4 2 4 ...
> names(approval)
[1] "PROMOTIONAL3" "OUGHT2"       "OUGHTTO3"     "OUGHTTO4"    
> str(approval)
'data.frame':   96 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ PROMOTIONAL3: int  4 3 3 4 4 1 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ OUGHT2      : int  5 2 4 5 3 3 5 4 4 3 ...
 $ OUGHTTO3    : int  5 2 3 5 4 5 5 4 2 3 ...
 $ OUGHTTO4    : int  4 2 3 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

I need a single number of their correlations, rather than multiple correlations between variables. Therefore, I convert the two data frames into vectors and attempted to get ONE correlation coefficient:

```
cor.test(c(as.matrix(ideal)), c(as.matrix(approval)))
```

But this error popped up:

```
Error in cor.test.default(c(as.matrix(ideal)), c(as.matrix(approval))) : 
'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Can anyone help? Very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I convert the two data frames into vectors and attempted to get ONE
>   correlation coefficient

Although this probably does not make much sense, but here is a starter:

```
ideal <- data.frame(
  IDEAL1 =c(4, 5, 3, 5, 5),
  IDEAL2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2))
approval <- data.frame(
  PROMOTIONAL3 = c(4, 3, 3),
  OUGHT2 = c(5, 2, 4)
)
# data frames to vectors
vec1 <- unlist(ideal)
vec2 <- unlist(approval)
# determine common length
l <- min(length(vec1), length(vec2))
# determine cor coef
cor(vec1[1:l], vec2[1:l])
# [1] -0.09697623
```

`vec1` and `vec2` have different length, thus I (i.e you) need to shorten one.